# Basis eigenvectors: fractions and negative equivalences

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am learning about eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and diagonalizing of matrices.

In this example, and in many others, whenever I am trying to find the basis eigenvectors for a specific eigenvalue, I am having a little problem with coming up with the exact same answer as the teacher's.

Take this example:

> *Diagonalize the following matrix:* $A = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

I am well able to find the same eigenvalues as my teacher: $\lambda = 5$ and $\lambda = 0$. Until there, things are okay.

I then proceed to find the vector spaces generated by the eigenvectors of $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 5$.

For $\lambda = 5$, I am able to find the same answer as the teacher's:

$\left( \begin{array}{cc|c}-1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & -4 & 0 \end{array} \right) \sim \left( \begin{array}{cc|c}-1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)  \Rightarrow -x_1 + 2 x_2= 0 \Rightarrow x_1 = 2 x_2, \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = x_2 \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

However, for $\lambda = 0$, it's when I have an issue.

I did the following: $\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 4 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right) \sim \left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right) \Rightarrow x_1 = -\frac{1}{2}x_2 \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix} = x_2 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

My professor did...  $\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 4 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right) \sim \left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 4 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) \Rightarrow x_2 = -2 x_1 \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix} = x_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}$

It makes is so, at the end, when it comes to expressing A with those eigenvectors and eigenvalues, I get:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ while my teacher gets: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$

In my head, both relations between $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are equivalent. However, I was wondering if my answer was "wrong" in any way - because of conventions or because of some key concept I may be missing.  I'm scared to lose points to homework/exams because of it, and when it comes to diagonalizing symmetric matrices, the difference is even worse.

Sorry if my question seemed long, I wanted to be as clear as possible. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Eigenvectors are only defined up to a multiple, since your and your teacher's answers are multiples of each other they are both right. His is "better" only in the sense that it doesn't have fractions, so the answers looks "prettier".

Comment: @Conifold thank you for clearing my doubts! I will try to beautify my vectors.

Comment: Conventionally, when you row-reduce a matrix, the result is in echelon form, which requires that the all-zero rows be at the bottom.